# GraphQL Request in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, graphql, gql

I don't know how to solve this problem I'm trying a long time now but I'm stuck.

I've tried different Libarys for GraphQL requests but nothing is working so thats why im searching for help.

I want to use the GraphQL request to get some details from some Axies on my wallet

it would be great if anybody can help me

```
from gql import gql, Client
from gql.transport.requests import RequestsHTTPTransport


header = {
    'User-Agent': 'My User Agent 1.0',
    'From': 'youremail@domain.com',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}


transport = RequestsHTTPTransport(url="https://graphql-gateway.axieinfinity.com/graphql",headers=header, use_json= True)

client = Client(transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport= True)

query = gql('''
{
    GetAxieBriefList{
  axies(
    auctionType: $auctionType
    criteria: $criteria
    from: $from
    sort: $sort
    size: $size
    owner: $owner
  ) {
    total
    results {
      ...AxieBrief
      __typename
    }
    __typename
  }
}

fragment AxieBrief on Axie {
  id
  name
  stage
  class
  breedCount
  image
  title
  battleInfo {
    banned
    __typename
  }
  auction {
    currentPrice
    currentPriceUSD
    __typename
  }
  parts {
    id
    name
    class
    type
    specialGenes
    __typename
  }
  __typename
}
}

''')

variables = {
    "from": 0,
    "size": 100,
    "sort": "IdDesc",
    "auctionType": "All",
    "owner": "<my0xAdress>"
    }

response_query = client.execute(query,variables)

print(response_query)
```

I'm getting this error and I do not know how to make the schema correctly

````
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Invalid or incomplete introspection result. Ensure that you are passing the 'data' attribute of an introspection response and no 'errors' were returned alongside: None.```
````

Answer (score 0):

For newer gql versions, you should use the client as:

```py
 with client as sess:
        response = sess.execute(query, variables)
```

Once you implemented this, another reason for the error can be invalid authentication headers. Recheck if you are passing all necessary headers to the transport.

You can add a print statement (or use more advanced debugging methods if you want to but simple is better) to the source to inspect the response for errors.

Path: `gql/client.py`

```py
def fetch_schema(self) -> None:
        """Fetch the GraphQL schema explicitely using introspection.

        Don't use this function and instead set the fetch_schema_from_transport
        attribute to True"""
        execution_result = self.transport.execute(parse(get_introspection_query()))
        # DEBUG statement on the response requesting schema
        print(execution_result)
        self.client.introspection = execution_result.data
        self.client.schema = build_client_schema(self.client.introspection)
```